# Sharepoint2013 CSOM vs REST API Data Services

Tags: sharepoint-2013

One of the drawback for using REST-API compared to using CSOM is that Object oriented programming is not possible with REST.

But if we use WCF Data Services(ADO.Net Data Services) then is it correct that we get almost all the benefits of CSOM in REST-API?

Comment: What do you mean that oop is not possible with REST? You can always create your wrapper class around REST api calls.

Comment: Also when you say "WCF Data Services" do you mean custom services?

Comment: WCF Data Services provides the wrapping possibilities. My question is would that be as good as CSOM

Comment: It depends what are you trying. Most of the functionality is present in both services but there could be some exceptions.

Comment: Okay, so use REST only if we need REST capabilities( eg: when calling from mobile devices) else CSOM is the best option. agree?